# jcarousel stop on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, jcarousel, carousel

I'm a graphic designer and I'm trying to code my new portfolio using some wonderful jquery scripts. I want to make jcarousel (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) stop on mouseover.

any help is appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an `initCallback` function that is called right after initialisation of the carousel.

This function will do the trick:
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/f550b94914d10065

Answer (score 2):

```
var isMouseOver = false;
$(this).mouseover(function(){
isMouseOver = true;
}).mouseout(function(){
isMouseOver = false;
});
//add by koumei--&gt;
function go(to) {
...
...
```

It is from http://blog.koumei.net/2011/06/01/jcarousel-lite-mouse-hover-event-improvement/

Answer (score 1):

To answer Geert's answer more thoroughly (btw, it works great),

within your settings you add the initCallback function:

```
initCallback: function(jc, state) { 
                if (state == 'init') { 
                /* Pause carousel scrolling when a user mouses overs an item and restart the scrolling when they mouse out. 
                * Written by cormac at finisco dot com 19/2/2009 based on work by Jeremy Mikola: 
                * http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/f550b94914d10065 
                */ 
                    jc.startAutoOrig = jc.startAuto; 
                    jc.startAuto = function() { 
                        if (!jc.paused) { 
                            jc.startAutoOrig(); 
                        } 
                    } 
                    jc.pause = function() { 
                        jc.paused = true; 
                        jc.stopAuto(); 
                    }; 
                    jc.play = function() { 
                        jc.paused = false; 
                        jc.startAuto(); 
                    }; 
                    $('li.jcarousel-item').mouseover(function() { 
                        jc.pause(); 
                    }); 
                    $('li.jcarousel-item').mouseout(function() { 
                        jc.play(); 
                    }); 
                };
                jc.play(); 
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Below function may be useful for stop animation

```
    itemLoadCallback: {
        onBeforeAnimation: function(jc,state){
          jc.lock();
     }
    }
```